# Checkbox validation using Docusign REST API

Tags: docusignapi

From Docusign Web UI, I am able to add a checkbox Group and add a validation like this:

[image]

But same validation is not available from any of the API. Is there any workaround or some other API endpoint to add this validation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is available through the API. The trick is that you have to set each Checkbox to have a Group, and then you have to assign the validation rules to the TabGroup. Here's an example:

```
            "tabs": {
                "checkboxTabs": [
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "Checkbox1",
                        "required": false,
                        "selected": false,
                        "pageNumber": 1,
                        "documentId": "1",
                        "recipientId": "1",
                        "tabGroupLabels": [
                            "Checkbox Group"
                        ],
                        "xPosition": 308,
                        "yPosition": 43,
                    },
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "Checkbox2",
                        "pageNumber": 1,
                        "documentId": "1",
                        "recipientId": "1",
                        "tabGroupLabels": [
                            "Checkbox Group"
                        ],
                        "xPosition": 308,
                        "yPosition": 59,
                    }
                ],
                "tabGroups": [
                    {
                        "groupLabel": "Checkbox Group",
                        "locked": false,
                        "groupRule": "SelectAtLeast",
                        "minimumRequired": 1,
                        "maximumAllowed": 1,
                        "validationMessage": "Please check a box",
                        "documentId": "1",
                        "pageNumber": 1,
                        "tabScope": "Document",
                        "recipientId": "1"
                    }
                ]
            }
```

To get an idea of how exactly to set up the group to have the validation rules you want, you might use [API logging](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) to capture the Web Console's AddEnvelopeTabs traffic. Do note that the web console uses two API calls (one to create the checkboxes, one to create the group), but your application can do it in one.

**Added**

The possible `groupRule` values are `SelectAtLeast`, `SelectAtMost`, `SelectExactly`, `SelectARange`. Use the value that fits your use case.

The associated attributes are `minimumRequired`, `maximumAllowed`, as appropriate to the `groupRule` setting.

Internal Jira DEVDOCS-2087 has been filed to have the docs updated.

Comment: Let me try this. This is helpful

Comment: The API Logging trick really helped. Opened up few other doors for me. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! This is the only proper documentation of this I could find on the internet :)