# Unable to create a tab group or associate it with an existing tab

Tags: java, docusignapi

I'm attempting to follow [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58209376/checkbox-validation-using-docusign-rest-api/58210277#58210277) about how to add a tab group to enforce a validation rule.

My tabs already exist on the document because I am using `transformPdfFields`. My process is:

1. Fetch Document Tabs using [Envelope Document Tabs GET](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocumentTabs/get).

```
envelopesApi.getDocumentTabs(accountId, envelopeId, documentId)
```

2. Modify an existing checkbox tab and add a Tab Group.

```
Optional<Checkbox> termsCheckboxOptional = tabs.getCheckboxTabs().stream().filter(checkbox -> {
  return checkbox.getTabLabel().equals("DocuSignAcceptTerms"); // make static
}).findFirst();

if (termsCheckboxOptional.isEmpty()) {
  return tabs;
}

Checkbox termsCheckbox = termsCheckboxOptional.get();

TabGroup checkboxGroup = new TabGroup();
checkboxGroup.setGroupLabel("Terms Checkbox Group");
checkboxGroup.setGroupRule("SelectAtLeast");
checkboxGroup.setMinimumRequired("1");
checkboxGroup.setMaximumAllowed("1");
checkboxGroup.setRecipientId(termsCheckbox.getRecipientId());
checkboxGroup.setDocumentId(termsCheckbox.getDocumentId());
checkboxGroup.setValidationMessage("Please accept the Terms and Conditions.");
checkboxGroup.setTabScope("document");

termsCheckbox.setName("hello test");
termsCheckbox.setTabGroupLabels(Arrays.asList(checkboxGroup.getGroupLabel()));
termsCheckbox.setSelected("false");

tabs.setCheckboxTabs(Collections.singletonList(termsCheckbox));
tabs.addTabGroupsItem(checkboxGroup);
```

3. Call the [Envelope Recipient Tabs UPDATE](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/update), using the modified tabs.

```
envelopesApi.updateTabs(accountId, envelopeId, recipientId, tabs);
```

I can see that the response from the update call (3) contains the tab group, and seems to have all data assigned correctly.

```
{
  "checkboxTabs": [
    {
      "xposition": "42",
      "yposition": "443",
      "documentId": "45",
      "font": "helvetica",
      "fontColor": "black",
      "fontSize": "size9",
      "height": "4",
      "locked": "false",
      "name": "hello test",
      "pageNumber": "2",
      "recipientId": "7c4b3830-07b9-4f3f-8072-23e3b48dfef6",
      "required": "false",
      "selected": "false",
      "tabGroupLabels": [
        "Terms Checkbox Group"
      ],
      "tabId": "d278d9a9-d40a-4f48-ac97-58ae04be4966",
      "tabLabel": "DocuSignAcceptTerms",
      "tabType": "checkbox",
      "width": "4",
      "xPosition": "42",
      "yPosition": "443",
    }
  ],
  "signHereTabs": [
    {
      "xposition": "297",
      "yposition": "477",
      "documentId": "45",
      "isSealSignTab": "false",
      "name": "SignHere",
      "optional": "false",
      "pageNumber": "2",
      "recipientId": "7c4b3830-07b9-4f3f-8072-23e3b48dfef6",
      "scaleValue": "1",
      "stampType": "signature",
      "tabGroupLabels": [],
      "tabId": "ba45f3ab-7e67-4572-aedd-a188d0f148e9",
      "tabLabel": "DocuSignSignHere",
      "tabType": "signhere",
      "xPosition": "297",
      "yPosition": "477",
    }
  ],
  "tabGroups": [
    {
      "documentId": "45",
      "groupLabel": "Terms Checkbox Group",
      "groupRule": "SelectAtLeast",
      "maximumAllowed": "1",
      "minimumRequired": "1",
      "recipientId": "7c4b3830-07b9-4f3f-8072-23e3b48dfef6",
      "tabGroupLabels": [],
      "tabScope": "document",
      "validationMessage": "Please accept the Terms and Conditions.",
    }
  ],
}}
```

However, my document does not have the constraint of the tab group. What's more, when I perform another Envelope Document Tabs GET, I do not see the TabGroup. I do see that the Checkbox is updated, and its changes are reflected on the document in the UI.

It is only TabGroups that I cannot seem to modify.