# How do I disable checkboxes in a group if a specific check box is checked?

Tags: docusignapi

This is for DocuSign API:
I have 6 checkboxes where the 6th checkbox is "Prefer not to answer".  If the 6th checkbox is checked, I want to clear and disable the first 5 boxes.  1 or more of the first 5 can be checked if the 6th box is not checked.  Overall, at least 1 box has to be checked.

I will be using the tab group method outlined in [Checkbox validation using Docusign REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58209376/checkbox-validation-using-docusign-rest-api) to require at least 1 box to be checked.  Will the "Prefer not to answer" have to be in a separate group?  If so, how do I make sure that at least 1 box is selected in one or the other group?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

** Update **
I can't seem to get the tabGroups to work.  Can you help me with the code?

```
                    <tabGroups>
                        <groupLabel>ChkBxGrpRace</groupLabel>
                        <groupRule>SelectAtLeast</groupRule>
                        <maximumAllowed>5</maximumAllowed>
                        <minimumRequired>1</minimumRequired>
                        <pageNumber>
                            <string>2</string>
                        </pageNumber>
                        <validationMessage>Please check one or more races, or Prefer not to answer</validationMessage>
                    </tabGroups>
```

Comment: I noticed I was missing DocumentID and have added it, but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps make two groups of checkboxes (five in one, and "Prefer not to answer" in the second). Add a [conditional field](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=gbo1643332197980&topicId=iqw1578456520131.html&_LANG=enus) rule that disables the first group if the second group is checked.

Protip: Define a template using the DocuSign webapp. Then your API call simply uses the template. It is much easier to define a template using the webapp than defining envelope features via the API.

Here's a [Live Example via the API Request Builder](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/?eg=Set%20template%20email%20and%20metadata%20with%20composite%20templates) that sends an envelope by using a template and filling in dynamic data when the envelope is sent.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  i first attempted to get tabGroups working but can't.  I have posted the XML code in the question.  Can you help?

Comment: @PSD -- please ask a new question. Stackoverflow is not a forum system. One subject per question

Comment: Sorry about that @Larry K.  After I get the tabGroup working, I will try the conditional field you suggested.  I will come back and accept your answer if I get it working.