# What is the tabGroups syntax for XML?

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to create a tabGroup for a group of checkboxes so that at least 1 has to be checked, but they keep coming up optional.  I referenced [Checkbox validation using Docusign REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58209376/checkbox-validation-using-docusign-rest-api) for tags needed.  I have also searched DocuSign documentation but cannot find syntax or examples for XML.
I have radioGroupTabs set up successfully so I mimicked the tags it uses to see if that would work - it doesn't.
Here is my code for the checkboxes:

```
    <checkboxTabs>
      <checkbox>
        <documentId>1</documentId>
        <recipientId>2</recipientId>
        <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>True</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
        <tabLabel>Race1</tabLabel>
        <name>chkRace1</name>
        <anchorString>chkRace1</anchorString>
        <anchorUnits>pixels</anchorUnits>
        <anchorXOffset>-16.7</anchorXOffset>
        <anchorYOffset>-3</anchorYOffset>
        <selected>False</selected>
        <tabGroupLabels>
          <string>ChkBxGrpRace</string>
        </tabGroupLabels>
      </checkbox>
      <checkbox>
        <documentId>1</documentId>
        <recipientId>2</recipientId>
        <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>True</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
        <tabLabel>Race2</tabLabel>
        <name>chkRace2</name>
        <anchorString>chkRace2</anchorString>
        <anchorUnits>pixels</anchorUnits>
        <anchorXOffset>-16.7</anchorXOffset>
        <anchorYOffset>-3</anchorYOffset>
        <selected>False</selected>
        <tabGroupLabels>
          <string>ChkBxGrpRace</string>
        </tabGroupLabels>
      </checkbox>
      <checkbox>
        <documentId>1</documentId>
        <recipientId>2</recipientId>
        <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>True</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
        <tabLabel>Race3</tabLabel>
        <name>chkRace3</name>
        <anchorString>chkRace3</anchorString>
        <anchorUnits>pixels</anchorUnits>
        <anchorXOffset>-16.7</anchorXOffset>
        <anchorYOffset>-3</anchorYOffset>
        <selected>False</selected>
        <tabGroupLabels>
          <string>ChkBxGrpRace</string>
        </tabGroupLabels>
      </checkbox>
      <checkbox>
        <documentId>1</documentId>
        <recipientId>2</recipientId>
        <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>True</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
        <tabLabel>Race4</tabLabel>
        <name>chkRace4</name>
        <anchorString>chkRace4</anchorString>
        <anchorUnits>pixels</anchorUnits>
        <anchorXOffset>-16.7</anchorXOffset>
        <anchorYOffset>-3</anchorYOffset>
        <selected>False</selected>
        <tabGroupLabels>
          <string>ChkBxGrpRace</string>
        </tabGroupLabels>
      </checkbox>
      <checkbox>
        <documentId>1</documentId>
        <recipientId>2</recipientId>
        <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>True</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
        <tabLabel>Race5</tabLabel>
        <name>chkRace5</name>
        <anchorString>chkRace5</anchorString>
        <anchorUnits>pixels</anchorUnits>
        <anchorXOffset>-16.7</anchorXOffset>
        <anchorYOffset>-3</anchorYOffset>
        <selected>False</selected>
        <tabGroupLabels>
          <string>ChkBxGrpRace</string>
        </tabGroupLabels>
      </checkbox>
      <checkbox>
        <documentId>1</documentId>
        <recipientId>2</recipientId>
        <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>True</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
        <tabLabel>RaceNA</tabLabel>
        <name>chkRaceNA</name>
        <anchorString>chkRaceNA</anchorString>
        <anchorUnits>pixels</anchorUnits>
        <anchorXOffset>-16.7</anchorXOffset>
        <anchorYOffset>-3</anchorYOffset>
        <selected>False</selected>
        <tabGroupLabels>
          <string>ChkBxGrpRace</string>
        </tabGroupLabels>
      </checkbox>
    </checkboxTabs>
    <tabGroups>
      <documentId>1</documentId>
      <groupLabel>ChkBxGrpRace</groupLabel>
      <groupRule>SelectAtLeast</groupRule>
      <maximumAllowed>5</maximumAllowed>
      <minimumRequired>1</minimumRequired>
      <recipientId>2</recipientId>
      <pageNumber>2</pageNumber>
      <validationMessage>Please check one or more races, or Prefer not to answer</validationMessage>
    </tabGroups>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the reason you are using the SOAP API and not the REST API?

Comment: I am using Rest API.  Why do you think it is SOAP?

Comment: You use REST API with XML? not JSON? maybe the question is why XML and not JSON?

Comment: We run from Access VBA.  To be honest, when we went with DocuSign 7 years ago, they gave us VBA code that built the envelope in XML, that we modified for our purpose.  At this time, we cannot re-engineer what we are doing, but I'm sure we will in the future.

Answer (score 0):

So, I'll post the JSON for this and you can use https://www.freeformatter.com/json-to-xml-converter.html can help convert to XML :

(note the **minimumRequired** field that is what you need)

```
{
    "checkboxTabs": [{
        "name": "",
        "tabLabel": "myTabLbl",
        "selected": "false",
        "selectedOriginal": "false",
        "shared": "false",
        "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "false",
        "font": "lucidaconsole",
        "bold": "false",
        "italic": "false",
        "underline": "false",
        "fontColor": "black",
        "fontSize": "size9",
        "shareToRecipients": "",
        "required": "false",
        "locked": "false",
        "documentId": "1",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "pageNumber": "1",
        "xPosition": "490",
        "yPosition": "69",
        "width": "0",
        "height": "0",
        "tabType": "checkbox",
        "trackingId": "c277",
        "tabGroupLabels": ["myGroupLbl"]
    }, {
        "tabLabel": "myTabLbl",
        "selected": "false",
        "selectedOriginal": "false",
        "shared": "false",
        "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "false",
        "font": "lucidaconsole",
        "bold": "false",
        "italic": "false",
        "underline": "false",
        "fontColor": "black",
        "fontSize": "size9",
        "shareToRecipients": "",
        "required": "false",
        "locked": "false",
        "documentId": "1",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "pageNumber": "1",
        "xPosition": "490",
        "yPosition": "85",
        "width": "0",
        "height": "0",
        "tabType": "checkbox",
        "trackingId": "c292",
        "tabGroupLabels": ["myGroupLbl"]
    }, {
        "tabLabel": "myTabLbl",
        "selected": "false",
        "selectedOriginal": "false",
        "shared": "false",
        "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "false",
        "font": "lucidaconsole",
        "bold": "false",
        "italic": "false",
        "underline": "false",
        "fontColor": "black",
        "fontSize": "size9",
        "shareToRecipients": "",
        "required": "false",
        "locked": "false",
        "documentId": "1",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "pageNumber": "1",
        "xPosition": "490",
        "yPosition": "101",
        "width": "0",
        "height": "0",
        "tabType": "checkbox",
        "trackingId": "c302",
        "tabGroupLabels": ["myGroupLbl"]
    }]
}

    {
        "tabGroups": [{
            "groupLabel": "myGroupLbl",
            "minimumRequired": "1",
            "maximumAllowed": "1",
            "groupRule": "SelectAtLeast",
            "tabScope": "Document",
            "documentId": "1",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "width": "0",
            "height": "0",
            "tabType": "tabgroup"
        }]
    }
```

Comment: I wish it were that easy, but it is not.  I tried many different ways with no luck.  Since we have to send out  our letters, we are letting them go without the conditional logic.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [Live example via the API Request Builder](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/?eg=Require%20one%20of%20multiple%20checkboxes) for a group of checkboxes.

You can output the example in different programming languages or JSON.

Comment: unfortunately, XML was not one of the languages, but thank you for this link as we have created a task to research templates again to see if our 79 dynamic letters can fit into one or more templates.  I will use this link and the task to convert to JSON.