# Docusign REST API : make checkboxTab required on an unknown page

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to add a required CheckboxTab on a document

I already found this answer explaining how to do it using a TabGroup :
[Checkbox validation using Docusign REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58209376/checkbox-validation-using-docusign-rest-api/58210277#58210277)

Problem is : since I don't know in advance where the CheckboxTab will be located in the document, i'm auto-placing it using an anchor string,

And for the TabGroup to function, one needs to pass the pageNumber parameter (which, given the latter, is unkwown)

Is there a way to achieve what I want to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an anchor string for each checkbox tab so that the tabs will be placed automatically in the document. Unfortunately the pageNumber and documentId fields are required for tab groups so you will need to know which page number the checkboxes should appear on if you want to use a tab group to enforce validation on the checkbox group.

Comment: One potential workaround could be to create a draft envelope with your checkbox tabs, then use the listTabs endpoint to get the tabs on the envelope. That response will include the pageNumber and documentId of each tab which you can then use to update your envelope with a tab group before sending it.

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipienttabs/list/

Comment: Thanks for you input, you confirmed that i can't do what i want based on anchors alone

Instead i'm going to try and detect the anchors on my side instead of using anchors